# concatMap with subject not working, with http.post working

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have an array of items that I want to POST to a server sequentially:

```
const items = ["a", "b", "c"];
```

In order to achieve that, I use `concatMap` together with Angular's `HttpService`. However, I don't directly want to use a `HttpService` call in `concatMap`, but rather use a third `Subject` for that:

```
sendItem(item: Item): Subject<boolean> {
    const result$ = new Subject();

    console.log(`Sending ${item}`);

    this.http.post('http://...', item)
        .subscribe(() => {
            // do stuff

            console.log(`Done sending ${item}`);

            result$.next()
        });
    return result$;
}

sendItems() {
    Observable.from(items)
        .concatMap(item => this.sendItem(item))
        .subscribe(() => console.log('Done with all items'););
}
```

My issue: Only the first item is ever sent. I can see that it completes (logs "Done sending a"), but `sendItem` is never called for "b" afterwards. I do get a "Done with all items" though.

The whole construct, however, works if I directly `http.post` in `concatMap`:

```
sendItems() {
    Observable.from(items)
        .concatMap(item => this.http.post('http://...', item))
        .subscribe(() => console.log("Done with all items"));
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I found the solution:

> concatMap does not subscribe to the next observable until the previous completes (https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/concatmap.html)

So if I do a `result$.complete()`, everything works just fine.